# Windows 10 subscription activation for hybrid Azure AD joined devices

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, entra-id

We have On Premises AD synced to Office365 (Azure) and Users having
"**Microsoft 365 E3**" Licences.

Dell Desktops with Windows 10 PRO 1803 version joined to On-Premises AD and they are Activated to Windows PRO using Dell Embedded Digital License.

Also Windows 10 Machines are showing in Azure AD Portal with "Hybrid Azure AD joined"

and dsregcmd /status shows AzureAdJoined : YES

But Machines are not getting upgraded from PROD to Enterprise ,

Can you please help me what can be done in this issue.

Please see attached for better understating

Is there any alternate Method or some Manual command or tool from which we can Upgrade them to Enterprise

any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which account is used when you sign in Windows 10? Make sure the end user signed in with his or her Azure AD account that is assigned with Windows 10 E3 or E5 license, not the local AD account.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to upgrade win10 from pro to enterprise, like using a provisioning package,  using a command-line tool or entering a product key manually.

**Upgrading using a command-line tool**

You can run the changepk.exe command-line tool to upgrade devices to a supported edition of Windows 10:

```
changepk.exe /ProductKey <enter your new product key here>
```

You can also upgrade using slmgr.vbs[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj612867(v%3Dws.11)) and a KMS client setup key by the following command:

```
Cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43
```

For the details, you can read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-edition-upgrades).

Comment: Dear Sunny, Thanks for your reply, there is no Product key for "Microsoft 365 E3" and they are upgraded Automatically as per the USer's Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Today we found a solution for this in our own environment, please try it and let me know:

1. Login as the Microsoft E3 or E5 licensed user.
2. Open Settings > System> Shared Experiences and click Fix on the account issue.
3. Log out and back in, see if it has upgraded.